# Different Values for Different Calculations of Specific Weight of Water in lbf/ft^3

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I have been trying to wrap my head around this, but I really can't figure it out. I don't understand why the value for the specific weight of water differs when I directly convert it from $\frac{N}{m^3}$ to $\frac{lb_f}{ft^3}$, and when I compute it using the formula for specific weight $\gamma=\rho g$

Converting it from $\frac{N}{m^3}$:

$$9810\frac{N}{m^3}\times(\frac{1m}{3.28ft})^3\times\frac{0.22lb_f}{1N}=62.4\frac{lb_f}{ft^3}$$

Using the formula $\gamma=\rho g$

$$\gamma=\rho g=(62.4\frac{lb}{ft^3})(32.2\frac{ft}{s})$$
$$\gamma=2009.28\frac{lb_f}{ft^3}$$

What is the cause of this? Is there something I'm missing? Something I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: 1kg is 2.2046 lb, so have you got all your conversions correct?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe 62.4 lbf/ft^3 calculated from converting from N/m^3 and 62.4 lb/ft^3 used in the formula of density*gravity are really the same thing. Why are you multiplying 62.4 by gravity?

Comment: Okay, I did a bit more of a searching that I think answers things. Pound-mass is dependent to pound-force in that pound-mass pertains to the mass that a pound-force acts upon, which means that pound-mass should converts 1:1 to pound-force. So what should actually happen is that we must divide the pound-mass by g again in order to find the real value. Otherwise, I should have used 1.94 slug/ft^3 for the density, which would yield similar results as direct conversion. Still not sure if my understanding is correct tho.

Comment: Your 32.2 should be $\frac {ft}{s^2}$. Metric is so much nicer - particularly in the case of water!

Comment: @Xyzar I think the key to understanding this is that density in lb/ft3 is not mass per unit volume, but rather gravitational force per unit volume.  So it already has the gravitational constant built in.  In other words, the 62.4 lb/ft3 represents rho * g, not just rho in the second equation.  Both current answers convey this mathematically, but I'm hoping this will clarify why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple mistake is the conversion from the matrix units to the imperial units has produced the weight density of water, $\gamma_w = \dfrac{62.4 lb_f}{ft^3}$. Note that $lb_f$ has already included the gravitational constant $g$, thus, unless you convert it back to the mass density $\rho = \dfrac{\gamma}{g}$, there is no need to apply the gravitational constant again.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Water - Density, Specific Weight and Thermal Expansion Coefficients](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-density-specific-weight-d_595.html)

> In the Imperial system the mass unit is the slug [sl], and is derived from the pound-force by defining it as the mass that will accelerate at $1 ft/s^2$ when a $1 lb_f$ acts upon it.

> The density of water is $1.940 sl/ft^3$ at 39 °F (4 °C), and the specific weight in Imperial units is:

\begin{align}
γ &= \rho\ g \\
&= 1.940 sl/ft^3 \times 32.174 ft/s^2 \\
&= 1.940 lb_f/(ft/s^2\times ft^3) \times 32.174 ft/s^2 \\
&= 62.4 lb_f/ft^3\end{align}